# Ionic/Angular dialog error - invalid link: DialogView

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am debugging a problem in my application by creating a stackblitz demo app. I'm stuck and can't figure out why when I click to open the dialog, I get the error mentioned in title of this question.

I am opening the dialog like this in home.ts:

```
 openDialog(){
    const resetModal : Modal = this.modal.create('DialogView', { arr: this.arr, callback: this.theCallback.bind(this) });
    resetModal.present();
  }
```

And it says that the DialogView is an invalid link although I've imported it correctly(seemingly). What could be wrong?

**Here is the link to the stackblitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kdzcwt?file=pages/home/home.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove single quote from `'DialogView'` to `DialogView`. single quote is only used for **lazy loaded page** with own module.